# Can I get an instance of a view by ID, like in Android?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a table view, which was added in Interface Builder. How can I get its instance in the view controller?

Is there a way like in Android by using `getViewById()`?

And if so where do I give the view its id?

Comment: in IOS u can set the tag

Comment: @iPatel: _Stop adding_ [iphone] to questions that aren't about iPhones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and add `UITableView` programmatically and use it object (*This is only for `UITableView`*).

```
self.tblView            = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.tblView.frame      = CGRectMake(0, 87, self.view.frame.size.width, 374);
self.tblView.delegate   = self;
self.tblView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tblView];
```

Here `self.tblView` is object of `UITableView` you can use it as per your requirement.

Or get each object of subview of `UIView`

```
NSArray *subViewArray = [self.view subviews];
for (id obj in subViewArray)
{
  // here **`obj`** get each object of subView of UIView.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ment the second way :)

Comment: This is not the proper way of doing it. The proper way is what @vishwa.deepak suggested. But the answer to your question is that you need to set tag of UITableView in Storyboard or XIB file. Then in your .m file call viewWithTag: method on the superview of UITableView. It'll return the UITableview instance which refers to your table view in Storyboard/xib. Don't forget to typecast the returned object in UITableview object, & your tableview's tag must not match with any other sibling view's tag.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are starter in iPhone sdk, the solution goes as follows:

1. At first in the .h file of your view controller, add these lines, `IBOutlet UITableview * myTableView;`
2. Now open the .Xib file of the same view controller and then link the `TableView` from the xib to the files owner, there the name of the `TableView` will appear.
3. Also link the delegate and data sources of the `Tableview`.

Comment: This is a much better way than iterating through the subviews.